# How to remove the sys object from the contentful CDA response?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, contentful

How can I remove the sys object from the Content Delivery API response for the getEntries method? I was trying to use the select search parameter for querying but it doesn't remove the sys object.

```
getProducts(query?: object): Promise<Entry<any>[]> {
    return this.cdaClient.getEntries(Object.assign({
      content_type: 'product',
      select: 'fields',
      include: 1
    }, query))
      .then(res => res.items);
```

Answer (score 1):

Heyooo.

Because of [the way how Contentful's linking mechanism work](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/links/) the JSON response of the collection endpoint includes two main parts – `items` and `includes`.

```
{
    "items": [
    {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Entry",
        "id": "4rJn9OJsBiAKmeoiiw40Ko",
      },
      "fields": {
        "name": "Menu for Humans",
        "stickiness": 999.3,
        "menuMeal": [
          {
            "sys": {
              "type": "Link",
              "linkType": "Entry",
              "id": "3HkMtbj6hqcMYEqWIOm6SQ"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },  
  ],
  "includes": {
    "Entry": [
      {
        "sys": {
          "id": "3HkMtbj6hqcMYEqWIOm6SQ",
          "type": "Entry",
          ...
        },
        "fields": {...}
      },
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

The entries in `items` reference other items from the `includes` object. The provided SDKs do some magic under the hood to resolve these for you so that you can access fields recursively down the tree (e.g. `entry.fields.anotherEntry.fields`) – no matter how the response structure looks like.

This is why [you unfortunately can't omit the `sys` property in the JS sdk](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.js/blob/c8e51784ed9ab85ee1d00e7766d284c17e4d80f0/lib/create-contentful-api.js#L357-L360) because it's needed for the link resolution.